# HSQLDB ORACLE user lacks privilege or object not found: REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: java, oracle11g, hsqldb

i have a little problem with an hsqldb test.

I use oracle 11g as datasource for my project and hsqldb-2.3.2.jar for test.

In one query, i have used this regexp `AND REGEXP_LIKE(CODE_SC, '*PL[0-9]_J5[1-9]$')`

And i can't test it with hsqldb, i have configured my datasource like this :

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:castor;sql.syntax_ora=true" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

and the sessionFactory with

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">fr.edf.mpv2.castor.persistance.HsqlOracleDialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">import.sql</prop>
```

i add all what i need in import.sql and it's working fine.

i have create a class with :

```
 public class HsqlOracleDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public HsqlOracleDialect() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerFunctions() {
            registerFunction("regexp_like", new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.BOOLEAN,
     "case when (regexp_like(?1,?2)) then 1 else 0 end)"));
    }
}
```

but i get this error :

`user lacks privilege or object not found: REGEXP_LIKE`

does i have forgot to declare something?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You used the original function `REGEXP_LIKE` in the definition of your custom function. So when HSQLDB tries to create it, it fails because it's looking for a built-in function with this name to delegate the implementation to.

HSQLDB's built-in function `REGEXP_MATCHES` seems to be Oracle's `REGEXP_LIKE` counterpart, so this should work :

```
@Override
protected void registerFunctions() {
  registerFunction(
    "regexp_like",
    new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.BOOLEAN, "regexp_matches(?1,?2)")
  );
}
```